# Sending post to the database only works for the first submit

Tags: php, android, mysql

Updated - Code Formatting

I am trying to allow a user to submit a post. So far when a post is submitted it goes into the database with 'post' being empty. For some reason the text is not correctly going into the database but all the other information, such as id, date_added and added_by are correctly submitting. Also when submitting another post, it fails and I get the error, Could not create post. Here is the code:

```
        <?php

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

        require_once('connect.inc.php');

        $post = $_POST['POST'];

        $date_added = date("y-m-d");
        $added_by = "testuser";

        $sql = "INSERT INTO IDEAS VALUES ('', '$post', '$date_added', '$added_by')";

        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
            echo "created";
        }else{
            echo "Could not create post";
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);
    }

?>
```

Also, this is being used for an android app, how can I fetch the current user that is logged to be assigned to the variable $added_by? Do I call my login.php file in the beginning and use the username variable?

Comment: could you put the html elements too.

Comment: Try to print `$post` before `$sql`.

Comment: There are no html elements since this is being used for an android app. I am using Postman to test the file which is where I am getting the error. All I am submitting is text which should be assigned to $post

Comment: Try binding the parameters instead of directly including the text in the sql statement.

Comment: @AkhilVL echo $post is blank which makes sense.

Comment: What is actually in the $_POST? Does the $_POST['POST'] really contain what you need?

Comment: I understand it's not easy testing a request from a mobile app. On the server side you can try dumping the post data in the error log to see if it gets populated correctly. Or you can write into the logcat in android and see it the post is correct.

Comment: @Rasclatt sorry I am pretty new to PHP, I am not sure how I would go about in correctly binding the parameters.

Comment: Here is the link on how to do it: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php I use a PDO connection, so I can't really give you a fast and quick demonstration.

Comment: @SergeyVidusov It seems like nothing is going into the $_POST which is why I am having trouble. I want whatever the user types into the text field to be going into the post.

Comment: Post your form html, that my have issues.

Comment: @frz3993 I have not really done anything on the android side yet besides logging in and registering users. I want to finish the rest API before doing anything with android so I can base my application on that. I imagine I will run into more problems once I start connecting it to android.

Comment: @Rasclatt I do not have a form since this will be used from a mobile app. Right now I am simply using Postman to submit data to the database. I am currently looking at the link you sent me thank you.

Comment: Ok then for sure you will want to parameterize your queries. Anyone could use something like `cURL` to send your page post data that will mess your database right up.

Comment: 1. is the parameter name in the request (postMan) correct? i mean uppercase `POST` ? 2. it might looks stupid just try another name, something like `mydata` instead of `POST` as parameter name

Comment: @Rasclatt I would move this discussion to chat but I dont have the reputation. I am having trouble binding the parameters. This is what I have:        `$sql = "INSERT INTO IDEA VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
  $sql->bind_param('sss', $post, $date_added, $added_by);
  
  $post = $_POST['POST'];
  $date_added = date("y-m-d");
  $added_by = "testuser";
  
  $sql->execute();
  $sql->close();`

Comment: Have you ever thought of doing PDO instead? It's much easier when it comes to this stuff. For example, on a PDO you can do: `$q = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (:0,:1,:2)"); $q->execute(array(':0'=>$val1,':1'=>$val2,':2'=>$val3));` I find PDO so much easier to use than `mysqli_`

Comment: @Rasclatt I have not thought of using PDO. I feel like it is a whole different thing I will have to learn. I think im going to stick with mysqli. I got everything entering into the database correctly now, but I am still unable to submit more than one entry. I have also not figured out how to succesfully bind the parameters yet.

Comment: @Yazan you were right, postman was having trouble with the name. I changed the name and figured out why it wasn't entering data, however I am still only able to submit one entry and then get an error when trying to submit again.

Comment: Well I'm embarrassed... I forgot to auto increment my primary key. It is now letting me submit more than one. Sigh. Now to change everything to work with binding parameters.